# What is the title of this fantasy book about kingdoms, thieves, wyverns, orbs, and prophecy?

Tags: story-identification, novel, magic

The opening scene was a pub, I believe, where an apprentice was introduced.  The book took place in a world with kings and magicians, possibly mages, pretty sure elves or dwarves, and possibly wyverns, but the books described creatures that were like giant, dragon-size bats with enormous jaws.

The kingdom was corrupt.  The 3 adviser magicians were practicing evil magic.  Meanwhile, different factions were trying to track down and get their hands on several orbs, the idea being that whoever held the orbs had the power. There was also a prophecy of a sleeping king who would awaken to restore order to the region.

I know I read the book during 2012, and the copy I had gotten ahold of looked worn down, like it was from the 90s or older.  Any leads?

Comment: This user seems to be looking for the same novel; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/187161/castles-kings-magicians-mages-four-orbs-giant-bats-prophecy-caves-hills

Answer (score 4):

Could this be [The Sleeping King](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/23847975-the-sleeping-king) by Cindy Dees?

[This review](http://bookpassionforlife.blogspot.com/2015/09/review-sleeping-king-by-cindy-dees.html) mentions many of the trope items you've indicated above.

> In this adventure fantasy story **we have a world – Urth – that has
>   varying lands and inhabitants. Magic is aplenty but so is the tyranny.**
>   We start the book with events that happened years ago, a controlling
>   emperor who can bend anyones thoughts and will to his own, his power
>   hungry overlords who rule regions of Urth in any manner they choose as
>   long as they line the Emperor’s pockets and some good people who a
>   forced to make sacrifices for the greater good…… but there is also a
>   prophecy…. One that portends the downfall of the Emperor and his
>   regime! The emperor will do everything in his power to stop this from
>   happening but can you change fate?
>
> Fast forward a few years and **we meet Will, a young lad on the brink of
>   adulthood wanting to prove to his parents that he should be allowed to
>   train & fight for his little village.** Little does he know that his
>   village will need fighting for very soon and everything he thought he
>   knew – is not all there is to know. He is sent on an errand to a
>   nearby city to report to one person alone and to warn them that the
>   enemy is moving and they need to prepare – but will he be taken
>   seriously when the Governor of the city is corrupt as they come?
>
> Elsewhere Raina is on the verge of becoming a woman, 16 and on the
>   cusp of life – that is until she has a family tradition thrust upon
>   her that will change everything and leave her all but caged.
>   Headstrong Raina will refuse her family tradition, she will not accept
>   what is laid out for her and she will flee her home in a desperate
>   escape from a life that she doesn’t want. **With help from a mysterious
>   Elf she will search for a way to relieve her family from its duty so
>   that no other daughter will be forced to accept a fate like that which
>   is waiting for her.**
>
> Both Will and Raina believe the answer to their problems is in **the
>   prophecy of the ‘Sleeping King’ who will conquer all and bring the
>   world back into balance.** They head out with some friends in the hopes
>   they will find the Kings resting place so they can awaken him…..but
>   many enemies await and they journey will be full of danger – will they
>   set a prophecy in motion? Will they wake the Sleeping King?

Comment: That's quite a long quote. Could you possibly bold up the parts which match this OP's description, so that it's easier to tell at a glance whether it's a good match for the question?

Comment: I have the book and there is nothing about orbs or giant bats in it

Comment: Thanks for the input!! I have come across the Sleeping King, but I firmly remember the author being a man, AND someone told me the author wrote some of the D&D books, although I do not know if that is true..  The book title did not have anything about Orbs or Sleeping Kings that I recall.  It's unfortunate I can't remember character names, or even the name of the land, but I do know it was all make believe, like no familiar cities of countries, and no dates.